# User registration from mobile app

Tags: ios, api, oauth-2.0, registration

I have a mobile app which allows a user to login with his username/password credentials via an oAuth2 API. In addition to this flow, I would like a new app user to be able to sign up for a new account.

Is that something I could/should handle via the oAuth API?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to use a third-part API, like facebook, is very simple to implement and provides a great level of security.